# Audio recorder in 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10

I installed audio-recorder in Ubuntu 13.10, as I did before in 13.04, and had lots of problems: no sound even after had removed the program and rebooted, Sound manager not working properly, etc. I don't understand why people do not advice audio-recorder in not a good choice anymore, and I wonder which could be the best choise now.

Answer (score 2):

Find Audacity in Ubuntu Software center and its works good.

How to do it: [here](http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.fr/2015/05/record-playing-sounds-with-audacity.html)

Comment: I need something to record the audio output. I don't think Audacity does the thing.

Comment: Hope this One is good http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-audio-recorder-on-ubuntu-13-0412-10.html

Comment: Just now i Installed  in my desktop and works great ...

Comment: I did it already in a new installation of 13.10 and had troubles.